# Can't receive Gmail verification code for mail forwarding

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I have a unique low bandwidth system that only accepts emails from designated users.  I am trying to bypass that function by receiving emails from one "common" Gmail account and have them auto-forwarded to me.  But to do that, I have to view the verification code, well given that I don't know what the address is from the verification code, I can't register it as a user.

How can I bypass the verification code step and just start getting the email forwarding to work?

Answer (score 2):

The "Gmail Forwarding Confirmation" emails are sent from

```
Gmail Team <forwarding-noreply@google.com>
```

so if you can allow the emails from that address to be received, the problem would be solved.

I don't think there is any way around this confirmation process.